# Is there a module for scalable input / output for unlimited value fields?

Tags: 7, entities

In a field with unlimited values a user may easily enter 100+ items. While the db does allow unlimited entries, the client side input does not seem too scalable since it shows all values on the same page. Perhaps some kind of **paging** or Views would be great. Is there such a module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could of course write both a formatter and a widget to implement some sort of paging, but that doesn't change the fact that Drupal will always load all 100+ field items when loading the node *and* saving (by doing a DELETE first and then an INSERT) of all 100+ field items when saving that node.

There isn't really a nice way to do this properly using fields. In case of references (node, user, ..), a possible workaround is to reference those entities to the current one, so that each one only has one (or a few) references, instead of 100%. Then you can display them on the referenced entity using a view.

Using a non-relational field storage implementation like MongoDB can help with the storage performance problems because it's a single load/save operation, no matter how many fields and field items you have. But it's still one global operation for all field items at once.

Answer (score 1):

I have a workaround for this one. It is not pretty, but it works.

1. Make your field single value. (very important, so Drupal loads only one field item).You may use this item to hold some metadata about this field. I use it to save total number of field items.
2. Create another table, which holds your actual field values, indexed by the entity ID of your field.
3. In your formatter or widget, add the necessary pager to load current page 
   You must work your own part on save, delete and validation, essentially some form validation and submit code.

In this way, you only load the values of field per page, and you can even do AJAX on current page.

One issue I think it is worth to take attention: Drupal 7's behaviors is based on jQuery 1.4 (I suspect that .once has only jQuery 1.4 version). If you want to use features on jQuery 1.7 or later, you need to load it with noConflict function. I find it works perfectly with two versions of jQuery and jQueryUI on the same page.

Comment: Care to submit this on drupal.org as a module? :)

Answer (score 0):

I will try to make it a module. So far I have a module customized for one field with complicated data structure. I can do pagination, adding new field item by ajax, and sorting field item by JQueryUI Sortable. The field Item is themable.

Comment: This is not the answer. Please use comments.